# Rails: Will_paginate does not work properly after AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

Sorry about the repetition, I could not find the answers to my questions after a lot of searches. The will_paginate does not work after the `Ajax` call.

1. After delete action, It does not display the pages numbers at all (it simply returns  all results).
2. After search action, the page number does not update, it shows more pages than what should actually be there.

Here is the controller code.

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController

 def index
     @cities = City.get_cities(params[:city_name],params[:city_population]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js
  end

 end

 def create
      @city = City.new(params[:city])

  if @city.save
       flash[:success] = "City information saved successfully"

       redirect_to cities_path
    else
        render 'index'
    end
 end


def new
    @city = City.new
end


 def destroy
   @city = City.find(params[:id]).destroy
   @city.destroy
   @cities = City.all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to cities_path}
      format.js
    end
  end

 end
```

Here is the index view:

```
 <div class="row">
<h1>Search Cities or <%= link_to "Create New City", new_city_path %></h1>
<h3>99 random city information are generated in the database </h2>
<h3>Simply type any letter or city population between 0 and 10 to filter out</h3>
<%= form_tag "/cities/index", method: :get, remote: true do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "City Name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'city_name' %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "City Population greater than, in units of 1 million:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'city_population' %>
  <label></label>
  <%= button_tag("Search", :class => "btn") %>
<% end %>
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>


<div id='table' class="table table-striped">
    <%= render 'table' %> 
</div>


<%=will_paginate @cities %>
 </div>
```

Here is the partial view of the table:

```
<div class="row">
<h1>Enter City descriptions or <%= link_to "Search Cities", cities_path %></h1>
<%= form_for @city, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>

<%= f.label :city_name %>
<%= f.text_field :city_name %>

<%= f.label :city_description %>
<%= f.text_field :city_description %>

<%= f.label :city_population_in_units_of_millions %> 
<%= f.text_field :city_population %>
<label></label>

<%= f.file_field :image%>

<label></label>
<%= f.submit "Create new City", :class => "btn"%>
<% end %>
</div>

Finally two js.erb codes associated with index and delete actions:

index.js.erb:

$('#table').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('table')) %>');

destroy.js.erb:

$('#table').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('table')) %>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by myself.

add `<%= will_paginate @cities %>` into partial file

and change `@cities = City.all` to

> @cities = City.all.paginate(page: params[:page])

because `will_paginate` does not expect an `array` of objects.

Answer (score 0):

write in your controller

```
def index
  @cities = City.get_cities(params[:city_name],params[:city_population]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
   format.js  
  end 
end
```

in your view folder create `index.js.erb` and write

```
$('id or class').html('<%=escape_javascript render :partial => which part you update %>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and it was the same as before. The ajax works. The problem still persists as the will_paginate does not update at all........